# Load Images Tensorflow using tf.Data using scalars throws exception

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the official guide on how to load your own image data with tf.Data at [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images).

I am trying to use the tf.Data process.

This code:

```py
def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES
```

returns a rank 1 EagerTensor consisting of Boolean values. Which works when used in the following code:

```py
def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

This code:

```py
def get_label_nums(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  class_num = CLASS_NAMES.tolist().index(parts[-2])
  return class_num

def process_path_with_nums_as_labels(file_path):
  label = get_label_nums(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
labeled_nums_ds = list_ds.map(process_path_with_nums_as_labels, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

does not.

I have tried to use scaler numbers as that's what I am used to seeing but every time I try to process the data I get:
`OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a`tf.Tensor`as a Python`bool`is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.`

I have tried changing it to a `ndarray` regular tensor, decorated the function with `@tf.function` and I still can't get it to work. As far as I'm aware I am not using the tensor as a bool, only trying to use it as my label. Please tell me why I can use that tensor of bools and not scaler labels.

Answer (score 0):

The *OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError* is a very common error that is thrown when your function returns a python datatype/data-structure where a tensor is required. A tensor, unlike a np array or python list, is embedded into the tf graph. Since your class_num variable isn't a tensor, it cannot be mapped to the dataset.
You can fix this by either parsing the class_num index to a tf.constant like so: 
`class_num = tf.constant(class_num,dtype=tf.int32)` 
**OR** 
By wrapping the python function as a tf.py_function() like so:

```
def get_label_nums(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  class_num = CLASS_NAMES.tolist().index(parts[-2])
  return class_num

def process_path_with_nums_as_labels(file_path):
  label = get_label_nums(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = open(file_path).read() # note that this returns the image string, similar to tf.io.read_file()
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

def create_targets_map_fn(img_path):
  img,label = tf.py_function(process_path_with_nums_as_labels,inp=[img_path],Tout=(tf.float32,tf.int32))
  return img,label  
labeled_nums_ds = list_ds.map(create_targets_map_fn)
```